# Using ArcPy for large intersect/loop?

Tags: arcpy, intersect

I have two really large datasets, one with about 3 million hexagon features that span the extent of Pennsylvania being used as 'zones', and one with about 4 million features.

I need to run a tabular intersect with these datasets and then perform some formatting and deletion of records. My script works on a subset of the data (at the county level). When I try to run on the full datasets, it runs for about two hours and then produces an empty dataset.  This is understandable because I imagine something is happening with the size of the datasets.

However, I tried to create a loop to select hexagons by county and perform the intersect with those hexagons. When I try this, it will successfully perform the first intersect in the loop and output a table for Adams County, and then fail.  When I ran it in PyScripter, I got the following error:

```
[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Following the advice [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124969/python-ides-pyscripter-pythonwin-crashing-when-installed-with-arcgis-for-deskt), I uninstalled PyScripter and began just using IDLE as my IDE.  When run from IDE, no error is given, it just ends after completing the first table in the loop. When I copy and paste it into the Python window in ArcGIS, it just crashes ArcMap.  Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy, os, datetime
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

target_features = r'C:\Users\mmoore\Documents\ArcGIS\COA_Species.gdb\PlanningUnit_Hex10acre'
join_features = r'C:\Users\mmoore\Documents\ArcGIS\COA_Species.gdb\SGCN_SDM'
outTable = r'C:\Users\mmoore\Documents\ArcGIS\COA_Species.gdb'
pa_county = r'C:\Users\mmoore\Documents\ArcGIS\COA_Species.gdb\PA_County'

county_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pa_county, "county_lyr")
target_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(target_features, "target")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pa_county, "COUNTY_NAM") as cursor:
    county_list = sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})
counties = [x.encode('UTF8') for x in county_list]

for county in counties:
    county_selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(county_lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", '"COUNTY_NAM" = ' + "'%s'" %county)
    target_selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(target_lyr, "INTERSECT", county_selection, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
    intersect = os.path.join(outTable, county)
    classFeatures = ["ELCODE", "SeasonCode", "OccProb"]
    arcpy.TabulateIntersection_analysis(target_selection, "unique_id", join_features, intersect, classFeatures)

    case_fields = ["unique_id", "ELCODE", "SeasonCode"]
    max_field = "PERCENTAGE"
    sql_orderby = "ORDER BY {}, {} DESC".format(",".join(case_fields), max_field)

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(intersect, "*", sql_clause=(None, sql_orderby)) as cursor:
        case_func = itemgetter(*(cursor.fields.index(fld) for fld in case_fields))
        for key, group in groupby(cursor, case_func):
            next(group)
            for extra in group:
                cursor.deleteRow()
```

Comment: Why are you deleting rows in the update cursor?  I would also recommend initially running the script line by line through the python console in ArcMap and writing various l print statements to a temp text file so you can determine at what point or query it is crashing at.

Comment: I am deleting rows so that I can keep unique values of the highest proportion overlap and delete all others.  I am working with species here, so if the same species overlaps a hexagon, I want to keep the attributes of the one with the highest proportion overlap.  So, my update cursor sorts based on percentage and deletes the extras within the group.  This works if I run it line by line with one county (without the loop/select by location), but I will insert some print statements and see what I get.

Comment: To what percent value are you deleting the extras (you do not have an if conditional logic within the update cursor loop)?  In general deleting feature(s) from a database can take much time.  Performance wise it should be much faster to select all features above a certain percent and export that subset to a new features class.

Comment: The update cursor itself works well.  When running it on a table at the county level with hundreds of thousands of records, it takes seconds.  What it is doing is sorting within groups, leaving the first record within the group and deleting the extras.  So, for records that have the same unique ID, ELCODE, and SeasonCode, it is sorting by descending percent and deleting those beyond the first record.